# Semigroup-like thing where the append operation can fail

Tags: scala, scalaz

Suppose I have some type with an associative binary operation that feels a lot like `append` except that the operation may fail. For example, here's a wrapper for `List[Int]` that only allows us to "add" lists with the same length:

```
case class Foo(xs: List[Int]) {
  def append(other: Foo): Option[Foo] =
    if (xs.size != other.xs.size) None else Some(
      Foo(xs.zip(other.xs).map { case (a, b) => a + b })
    )
}
```

This is a toy example, but one of the things it has in common with my real use case is that we *could* in principle use the type system to make the operation total—in this case by tracking the length of the lists with something like Shapeless's `Sized`, so that adding lists of unequal lengths would be a compile-time error instead of a runtime failure. That's not too bad, but in my real use case managing the constraints in the type system would require a lot more work and isn't really practical.

(In my use case I have a sensible identity, unlike in this toy example, but we can ignore that for now.)

Is there some principled way to do this kind of thing? Searching for `a -> a -> m a` or `a -> a -> Maybe a` on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) doesn't turn up anything interesting. I know I can write an ad-hoc `append` method that just returns its result wrapped in whatever type I'm using to model failure, but it'd be nice to have something more general that would give me `foldMap1`, etc. for free—especially since this isn't the first time I've found myself wanting this kind of thing.

Comment: you might be interested in `MonadPlus` with `mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a`

Comment: @cdk: Thanks—yes, I know about `MonadPlus`, but don't see how it helps here, since my append logic is specific to the `a`.